# obtain value from div containing a @html.ValueFor() using jQuery

Tags: jquery

how to I obtain the value from the following DIV which contains a @html.ValueFor()? and place in a var variable.

```
<div ID="Rem">
    @html.ValueFor(model=>model.value)
</div>
```

```js
var MyVal = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you mean?

```
 var MyVal = $('#Rem').text();
```